# Flex center horizontally and adjust to content

Tags: html, css, flexbox, centering

I got 3 tabs: A, B and C. 
Each tab contains differently sized content. A and B are relatively short sized horizontally but can grow vertically, however C contains a table that can grow vertically as well but mostly horizontally.

I would like to center everything (including the tabs themselves) horizontally, so that regardless on what tab you click on everything is always centered (horizontally) and is adjusted to the content (fills x percent of the view or 100% with a scrollbar in case of an overflow, i.e. the table grows too wide).

After trying different kinds of flexbox configurations I always wind up either having non centered or cut off content. The latter meaning the view is cut off on the left side - including half of the A-tab - when one is clicking on the C-tab.

So far I got (I ommited some divs in between):

```
+---------.content----------+
|                           |
|    +-----------------+    |
|    |  A  |  B  |  C  |    |
|    +-----------------+    |
|    |                 |    |
|    |                 |    |
|    |                 |    |
|    +-----------------+    |
+---------------------------+

.content {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
}
```

However with this - like described above - the contents are cut off on the left side - when clicking on the C-tab (which contains the table, that doesn't fit the viewport)

Comment: There's something about your code which is missing.

Answer (score 1):

`display: flex` only affects its direct descendants.

Tables are also an unusual beast.

Without knowing more and being unable to ask for more information in a comment first (silly SO app), I would suggest you try to reduce your nested descendants to the least possible.

I would also suggest looking into `table-layout: fixed` and "how to make tbody scrollable"